# How to pass Array of Objects as parameter in Java swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, modelattribute

I need to **pass an array of objects as parameter in java Swagger UI**. I am unable to do it. However I can easily pass array of string as parameters. But **cant figure out how to pass array of objects nested inside another class or DTO.** I am using Java Spring and developing RESTful webservice.

Below is my 1st DTO that is passed as ModelAttribute in my REST api as parameter:

```
public class BusinessDetailsDTO {

    private BusinessMembersDTO[] businessMembers;

    public BusinessMembersDTO[] getBusinessMembers() {
        return businessMembers;
    }
    public void setBusinessMembers(BusinessMembersDTO[] businessMembers) {
        this.businessMembers = businessMembers;
    }
}
```

Below is 2nd DTO whose array is made property in 1st DTO:

```
public class BusinessMembersDTO {

    private String ownerRole;
    private String businessLocation;
    private Long memberId;
    //getter setter below 
}
```

Below is the controller method definition:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Add business info")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addBusinessInfo", produces={"application/json"})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = ResponseEntity.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure") })
    public ResponseEntity<BusinessDetails> addBusinessInfo(@RequestParam(
            @ModelAttribute BusinessDetailsDTO businessDetailsDTO) {
```

My problem is, I am unable to figure out **how should I pass values `ownerRole` which is present in `BusinessMembersDTO`**. 
**The swagger UI shows `Array[]` in DataType column next to `businessMembers` members field.**

Plz help.

Comment: Will having `BusinessDetailsDTO` hold a list of `BusinessMembersDTO`s (as opposed to an array of `BusinessMembersDTO`) help guiding Swagger UI's DataType column?

Comment: Never thought of it. Though it looks promising to me. Will try and surely revert back with the result. Thanks

Comment: Its still Not working.
added `private List<BusinessMembersDTO> businessMembersDTO;`
in 1st DTO but no luck

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should also add a getter and a setter to accompany this new `private List<...>` field. Can you try that?

Comment: I've already tried with getter setter only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put BusinessDetailsDTO directly as response in ApiResponse as below

> @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = BusinessDetailsDTO.class)

Comment: I need to get BusinessDetailsDTO as parameter, not about sending in response.

Comment: RequestParam could be a literal only. You can try @RequestBody

Comment: not helpful. The thing you are telling me is not related to the problem i have stated in my question.

Comment: If you wish to customize the existing Swagger functionality, please go through this blog https://anilagrawal038.wordpress.com/2016/12/25/custom-springfox-plugin-for-api-request-body-modeltype/

Comment: As for I know, nested objects are not supported for @RequestParam. Please go through https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1134